# Error while using ruby cucumber and calabash?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, calabash-android

/usr/bin/ruby -EUTF-8 -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /usr/bin/cucumber /Users/aalra01/RubymineProjects/wendys-android/Wendys/features/menu/menu.feature --format Teamcity::Cucumber::Formatter --expand --name "^The menu items are separated into their respective categories$" --color -r features Testing started at 10:15 AM ... Given I am on the menu # features/step_definitions/menu/menu.rb:18 When I select the  category # features/step_definitions/menu/menu.rb:24 Then I am taken to the  section # features/step_definitions/menu/menu.rb:34 2102 KB/s (560131 bytes in 0.260s) 2167 KB/s (9053374 bytes in 4.079s) java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.wendys.wendys.test/sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.CalabashInstrumentationTestRunner} from pid=2814, uid=2814 not allowed because package com.wendys.wendys.test does not have a signature matching the target com.wendys.wendys at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540) at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493) at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startInstrumentation(ActivityManagerNative.java:3609) at com.android.commands.am.Am.runInstrument(Am.java:950) at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:316) at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47) at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:99) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:249) HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected: HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected: ./features/support/screen_object/element_definers.rb:4:in `block in element' ./features/support/screen_object/element_definers.rb:35:in`block in button' ./features/step_definitions/menu/menu.rb:21:in `/^I am on the menu$/' ./features/menu/menu.feature:10:in`Given I am on the menu' Skipped step Skipped stepCould not take screenshot com.android.ddmlib.TimeoutException at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:648) at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:616) at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.getFrameBuffer(AdbHelper.java:296) at com.android.ddmlib.CalabashAdbHelper.getFrameBuffer(Unknown Source) at com.android.ddmlib.CalabashDevice.getScreenshot(Unknown Source) at sh.calaba.screenshot.ScreenshotTaker.takeScreenshot(Unknown Source) at sh.calaba.screenshot.ScreenshotTaker.main(Unknown Source) java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.wendys.wendys.test/sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.CalabashInstrumentationTestRunner} from pid=2831, uid=2831 not allowed because package com.wendys.wendys.test does not have a signature matching the target com.wendys.wendys at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540) at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493) at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startInstrumentation(ActivityManagerNative.java:3609) at com.android.commands.am.Am.runInstrument(Am.java:950) at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:316) at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47) at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:99) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:249) HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected: HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected: ./features/support/screen_object/element_definers.rb:4:in `block in element' ./features/support/screen_object/element_definers.rb:35:in`block in button' ./features/step_definitions/menu/menu.rb:21:in `/^I am on the menu$/' ./features/menu/menu.feature:10:in`Given I am on the menu' Skipped step Skipped stepCould not take screenshot com.android.ddmlib.TimeoutException at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:648) at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:616) at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.getFrameBuffer(AdbHelper.java:296) at com.android.ddmlib.CalabashAdbHelper.getFrameBuffer(Unknown Source) at com.android.ddmlib.CalabashDevice.getScreenshot(Unknown Source) at sh.calaba.screenshot.ScreenshotTaker.takeScreenshot(Unknown Source) at sh.calaba.screenshot.ScreenshotTaker.main(Unknown Source) java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.wendys.wendys.test/sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.CalabashInstrumentationTestRunner} from pid=2848, uid=2848 not allowed because package com.wendys.wendys.test does not have a signature matching the target com.wendys.wendys at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540) at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493) at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startInstrumentation(ActivityManagerNative.java:3609) at com.android.commands.am.Am.runInstrument(Am.java:950) at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:316) at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47) at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:99) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:249) HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected: HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected: ./features/support/screen_object/element_definers.rb:4:in `block in element' ./features/support/screen_object/element_definers.rb:35:in`block in button' ./features/step_definitions/menu/menu.rb:21:in `/^I am on the menu$/' ./features/menu/menu.feature:10:in`Given I am on the menu' Skipped step Skipped stepCould not take screenshot com.android.ddmlib.TimeoutException at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:648) at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:616) at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.getFrameBuffer(AdbHelper.java:296) at com.android.ddmlib.CalabashAdbHelper.getFrameBuffer(Unknown Source) at com.android.ddmlib.CalabashDevice.getScreenshot(Unknown Source) at sh.calaba.screenshot.ScreenshotTaker.takeScreenshot(Unknown Source) at sh.calaba.screenshot.ScreenshotTaker.main(Unknown Source) java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.wendys.wendys.test/sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.CalabashInstrumentationTestRunner} from pid=2865, uid=2865 not allowed because package com.wendys.wendys.test does not have a signature matching the target com.wendys.wendys at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540) at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493) at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startInstrumentation(ActivityManagerNative.java:3609) at com.android.commands.am.Am.runInstrument(Am.java:950) at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:316) at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47) at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:99) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:249) HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected: HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected: ./features/support/screen_object/element_definers.rb:4:in `block in element' ./features/support/screen_object/element_definers.rb:35:in`block in button' ./features/step_definitions/menu/menu.rb:21:in `/^I am on the menu$/' ./features/menu/menu.feature:10:in`Given I am on the menu' Skipped step Skipped stepCould not take screenshot com.android.ddmlib.TimeoutException at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:648) at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:616) at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.getFrameBuffer(AdbHelper.java:296) at com.android.ddmlib.CalabashAdbHelper.getFrameBuffer(Unknown Source) at com.android.ddmlib.CalabashDevice.getScreenshot(Unknown Source) at sh.calaba.screenshot.ScreenshotTaker.takeScreenshot(Unknown Source) at sh.calaba.screenshot.ScreenshotTaker.main(Unknown Source) java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.wendys.wendys.test/sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.CalabashInstrumentationTestRunner} from pid=2881, uid=2881 not allowed because package com.wendys.wendys.test does not have a signature matching the target com.wendys.wendys at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540) at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493) at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startInstrumentation(ActivityManagerNative.java:3609) at com.android.commands.am.Am.runInstrument(Am.java:950) at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:316) at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47) at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:99) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:249) HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected: HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected: ./features/support/screen_object/element_definers.rb:4:in `block in element' ./features/support/screen_object/element_definers.rb:35:in`block in button' ./features/step_definitions/menu/menu.rb:21:in `/^I am on the menu$/' ./features/menu/menu.feature:10:in`Given I am on the menu' Skipped step Skipped stepCould not take screenshot com.android.ddmlib.TimeoutException at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:648) at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:616) at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.getFrameBuffer(AdbHelper.java:296) at com.android.ddmlib.CalabashAdbHelper.getFrameBuffer(Unknown Source) at com.android.ddmlib.CalabashDevice.getScreenshot(Unknown Source) at sh.calaba.screenshot.ScreenshotTaker.takeScreenshot(Unknown Source) at sh.calaba.screenshot.ScreenshotTaker.main(Unknown Source) java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.wendys.wendys.test/sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.CalabashInstrumentationTestRunner} from pid=2899, uid=2899 not allowed because package com.wendys.wendys.test does not have a signature matching the target com.wendys.wendys at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540) at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493) at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startInstrumentation(ActivityManagerNative.java:3609) at com.android.commands.am.Am.runInstrument(Am.java:950) at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:316) at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47) at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:99) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:249) HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected: HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected: ./features/support/screen_object/element_definers.rb:4:in `block in element' ./features/support/screen_object/element_definers.rb:35:in`block in button' ./features/step_definitions/menu/menu.rb:21:in `/^I am on the menu$/' ./features/menu/menu.feature:10:in`Given I am on the menu' Skipped step Skipped stepCould not take screenshot com.android.ddmlib.TimeoutException at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:648) at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:616) at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.getFrameBuffer(AdbHelper.java:296) at com.android.ddmlib.CalabashAdbHelper.getFrameBuffer(Unknown Source) at com.android.ddmlib.CalabashDevice.getScreenshot(Unknown Source) at sh.calaba.screenshot.ScreenshotTaker.takeScreenshot(Unknown Source) at sh.calaba.screenshot.ScreenshotTaker.main(Unknown Source) java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.wendys.wendys.test/sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.CalabashInstrumentationTestRunner} from pid=2916, uid=2916 not allowed because package com.wendys.wendys.test does not have a signature matching the target com.wendys.wendys at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540) at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493) at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startInstrumentation(ActivityManagerNative.java:3609) at com.android.commands.am.Am.runInstrument(Am.java:950) at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:316) at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47) at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:99) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:249) HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected: HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected: ./features/support/screen_object/element_definers.rb:4:in `block in element' ./features/support/screen_object/element_definers.rb:35:in`block in button' ./features/step_definitions/menu/menu.rb:21:in `/^I am on the menu$/' ./features/menu/menu.feature:10:in`Given I am on the menu' Skipped step Skipped stepCould not take screenshot com.android.ddmlib.TimeoutException at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:648) at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:616) at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.getFrameBuffer(AdbHelper.java:296) at com.android.ddmlib.CalabashAdbHelper.getFrameBuffer(Unknown Source) at com.android.ddmlib.CalabashDevice.getScreenshot(Unknown Source) at sh.calaba.screenshot.ScreenshotTaker.takeScreenshot(Unknown Source) at sh.calaba.screenshot.ScreenshotTaker.main(Unknown Source) java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.wendys.wendys.test/sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.CalabashInstrumentationTestRunner} from pid=2933, uid=2933 not allowed because package com.wendys.wendys.test does not have a signature matching the target com.wendys.wendys at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540) at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493) at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startInstrumentation(ActivityManagerNative.java:3609) at com.android.commands.am.Am.runInstrument(Am.java:950) at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:316) at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47) at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:99) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:249) HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected: HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected: ./features/support/screen_object/element_definers.rb:4:in `block in element' ./features/support/screen_object/element_definers.rb:35:in`block in button' ./features/step_definitions/menu/menu.rb:21:in `/^I am on the menu$/' ./features/menu/menu.feature:10:in`Given I am on the menu' Skipped step Skipped stepCould not take screenshot com.android.ddmlib.TimeoutException at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:648) at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:616) at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.getFrameBuffer(AdbHelper.java:296) at com.android.ddmlib.CalabashAdbHelper.getFrameBuffer(Unknown Source) at com.android.ddmlib.CalabashDevice.getScreenshot(Unknown Source) at sh.calaba.screenshot.ScreenshotTaker.takeScreenshot(Unknown Source) at sh.calaba.screenshot.ScreenshotTaker.main(Unknown Source) java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.wendys.wendys.test/sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.CalabashInstrumentationTestRunner} from pid=2983, uid=2983 not allowed because package com.wendys.wendys.test does not have a signature matching the target com.wendys.wendys at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540) at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493) at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startInstrumentation(ActivityManagerNative.java:3609) at com.android.commands.am.Am.runInstrument(Am.java:950) at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:316) at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47) at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:99) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:249) HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected: HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected: Connection reset by peer ./features/support/screen_object/element_definers.rb:4:in `block in element' ./features/support/screen_object/element_definers.rb:35:in`block in button' ./features/step_definitions/menu/menu.rb:21:in `/^I am on the menu$/' ./features/menu/menu.feature:10:in`Given I am on the menu' Skipped step Skipped stepCould not take screenshot com.android.ddmlib.TimeoutException at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:648) at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:616) at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.getFrameBuffer(AdbHelper.java:296) at com.android.ddmlib.CalabashAdbHelper.getFrameBuffer(Unknown Source) at com.android.ddmlib.CalabashDevice.getScreenshot(Unknown Source) at sh.calaba.screenshot.ScreenshotTaker.takeScreenshot(Unknown Source) at sh.calaba.screenshot.ScreenshotTaker.main(Unknown Source) 9 scenarios (9 failed) 27 steps (9 failed, 18 skipped) 3m33.125s Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Could you give some more info please?  How are you running it?  Has this worked previously and isn't working now?  Is it running on iOS but not android or vice versa.  What version of calabash are you using?  Are you running this on a real device or on an emulator?  Also, could you cut down the error message in your post to be smaller and more readable please?  A lot of the bits from cucumber aren't relevant if nothing else. b It's quite difficult to read.

Comment: so there was nothing yesterday but now i have this problem , calabash and server both latest update ,only on android and run it on emulator .                        and i think this is the major error java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.wendys.wendys.test/sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.CalabashInstrumentationTestRunner} from pid=4482, uid=4482 not allowed because package com.wendys.wendys.test does not have a signature matching the target com.wendys.wendys

Comment: It looks like this is the relevant bit - Permission Denial: starting instrumentation Component

Comment: I've added what I think is the solution.  But can you edit your original post with the smaller error so that it can be useful to other users in the future please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error Permission Denial: starting instrumentation Component means that you don't have the right debug key.  If you have the keystore and it was working before then check that the keystore hasn't been updated.  If you don't have the keystore you can resign the app with your own.

```
calabash-android resign app.apk
```

From - https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/wiki/Running-Calabash-Android

> The apk calabash android runs must be signed with the same keystore as
>   the test-server.
>
> Use the command: calabash-android resign  to resign your
>   application.
>
> Building the test-server using calabash-android build  will build
>   the test-server and sign it with the same key as the application you
>   are testing.
>
> If debug.keystore is missing, it be recreated with the following
>   command:
>
> keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias
>   androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android -keyalg RSA
>   -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -dname "CN=Android Debug,O=Android,C=US"

Comment: i already tried this  calabash-android resign app.apk and there is nothing the same problem

Comment: Can you try recreating the keystore using the command from the end of my post and see how you get on with using that one?